# How to pass mock event to the react element that React.cloneElement() method returned

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

`index.ts`:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, cloneElement, Component, isValidElement } from 'react';

interface MyComponentProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentProps> {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    const items = React.Children.map(children, (element, index) => {
      if (!isValidElement(element)) {
        return element;
      }
      return cloneElement(element, {
        key: index,
        onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          element.props.onChange && element.props.onChange(e);
          // do other things
          console.log('handle change event');
        },
      });
    });
    return <div>{items}</div>;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import MyComponent from '.';

class Test extends React.Component<{ onChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void }> {
  render() {
    return <input {...this.props} />;
  }
}

describe('react-cloneElement-enzyme-change-event', () => {
  it('should handle change event', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MyComponent>
        <Test onChange={onChange} />
        <Test />
      </MyComponent>
    );
    const input = wrapper.find('div').children().at(0).find('input');
    // expect(jest.isMockFunction(input.prop('onChange'))).toBeTruthy(); // failed
    const event = {} as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
    input.simulate('change', event);
    expect(onChange).toBeCalled();
    expect(onChange).toBeCalledWith({}); // failed. The actual value is React synthetic event object
  });
});
```

This assertion `expect(onChange).toBeCalledWith({});` failed. I found that after executing `cloneElement`, the `onChange` event handler on `input` has been replaced with non-mock `onChange: () => {}`

So even if the mock event object is passed when the `input.simulate('change', event)` is executed, the `onChange` event handler is passed the React synthetic event object, NOT the mock event.

How can I pass the mock event object to the `onChange` of the cloned element?

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

Minimal, reproducible example repo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/issues/react-cloneElement-enzyme-change-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `onChange` prop is overridden with an anonymous arrow function.

We can use [.invoke(invokePropName)(...args) => Any](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/invoke.html#invokepropnameargs--any) invokes a function prop and passes our mocked event object to it.

E.g.

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import MyComponent from '.';

class Test extends React.Component<{ onChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void }> {
  render() {
    return <input {...this.props} />;
  }
}

describe('react-cloneElement-enzyme-change-event', () => {
  it('should handle change event', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MyComponent>
        <Test onChange={onChange} />
        <Test />
      </MyComponent>
    );
    const input = wrapper.find('div').children().at(0).find('input');
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(input.prop('onChange'))).toBeFalsy();
    const event = {} as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
    input.invoke('onChange')!(event);
    expect(onChange).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('handle change event');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  issues/react-cloneElement-enzyme-change-event/index.test.tsx
  react-cloneElement-enzyme-change-event
    ✓ should handle change event (84 ms)

  console.log
    handle change event

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |      90 |       75 |     100 |      90 |                   
 index.tsx |      90 |       75 |     100 |      90 | 13                
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.727 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `enzyme-adapter-react-16` has two different implementations for [simulateEvent](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js) for shallow and mount and for mount it's creating a mock event, which is merged with the given data.

So if you pass:

```js
    const event = {
      target: {
        value: 'z',
      },
    } as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
    input.simulate('change', event);
```

you can expect:

```
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining(event));
```